# Start SESSION with out Server side Script

Tags: php, html, session

Is it possible start Session with out using any server side scripting like PHP.

I want start SESSION with pure HTML/HTML5./Javascript.. ?

Thanks Advance. :)

Comment: There is no session then...

Comment: Nope, not possible, the best you could do would be with cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: use cookies as session

Answer (score 4):

The usual meaning of the term "session" in web development is "A bucket of information stored on the server that is linked to a specific user via a token". Since the definition requires a server to be involved, no you cannot achieve that without a server.

You *can* store the data in a session [cookie](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) (one without an explicit expiry time that will die when the browser is closed).

In modern browsers, you can store larger amounts of data using [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Storage).

Comment: I would reccomend against client-side storage, especially sessionStorage. See: http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/storage/risks-client-side-data-storage_33669

Comment: @Parrotmaster — I've only skimmed that, but it looks like it is saying "Don't blindly trust user input", which is nothing new.

Answer (score 2):

You could set a `COOKIE` with Javascript (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).
If you really want a PHP Session without PHP, that's impossible. A Cookie is the closest you'll get.

On the topic of Cookies, these are stored locally on the users system and can be edited. I do not reccomend using this method if you need good security. See this blog post explaining more on this matter: 
http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/12/cookies-and-security/

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible. What you use in PHP is the PHP session handler.

In javascript you can use cookies to store some small data.